# Which Gmail API should be enabled to use Gmail.Settings.Basic scope?

Tags: gmail-api, google-developers-console

I have Gmail API Enabled but I do not see `gmail.settings.basic` under that API.
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/gmail/v1/

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes), `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic` is one of the auth scopes which manage basic mail settings. You may use that scope if you authorize your requests using OAuth 2.0.

Example, you may use it in [`Users.settings.sendAs: get`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/sendAs/get) method.

[image]

Then, once you **authorize your requests using OAuth 2.0**, you will see the available scope you may use.

[image]

Hope this helps!